# Classifying space for Thompson's group F?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology, monoidal-categories, classifying-spaces

Let $\mathcal C$ be the free monoidal category generated by an object $X$, and a morphism $X \otimes X \to X$.

This category contains exactly two connected components: that of the monoidal unit $1\in \mathcal C$, and that of $X\in \mathcal C$. (In general, two object $A$ and $B$ of a category are said to be in the same connected component if they are related by a zig-zag of arrows $$A\to Y_1\leftarrow Y_2\to Y_3\leftarrow Y_4\to Y_5\leftarrow\ldots \to B.$$
In the case of $\mathcal C$, any two non-unit objects are related by a single morphism.)

Let $\mathcal C'\subset \mathcal C$ be the connected component of $X$ and 
let $|\mathcal C'|$ denote the geometric realisation (of the simplicial nerve) of $\mathcal C'$.

The article

> Marcelo Fiore, Tom Leinster, *An abstract characterization of Thompson's group $F$*, Semigroup Forum **80** (2010), 325-340,  doi:[10.1007/s00233-010-9209-2](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00233-010-9209-2),  arXiv:[math/0508617](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508617).

proves that $\pi_1(|\mathcal C'|)$ is isomorphic to Thompson's group $F$.

> **Question:** Is $|\mathcal C'|$ a classifying space for Thompson's group $F$?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: Fiore and Leinster talk about a different category, namely, the monoidal category freely generated by an object $X$ and an *isomorphism* $X \otimes X \to X$. That category is a groupoid, so your question has a positive answer for their category. Now it easily follows from their result that for your non-groupoid category the fundamental group is $F$, and you are asking if you also get a $K(F,1)$ from your category. Right?

Comment: @Omar Antolin-Camarera: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you describe is the so called Squier complex of the semigroup presentation
$\langle x \mid x^2=x\rangle$ (you did not describe the 2-cells, but it is straightforward). The fact that its fundamental group is $F$ was proved by Guba and myself in 1997, "Diagram groups", Memoirs of the AMS,
November, 1997 ([link](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-130-620/)). Farley in

> "Finiteness and CAT(0) properties of diagram groups", Topology **42** (2003), no. 5, 1065–1082 doi:[10.1016/S0040-9383(02)00029-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383%2802%2900029-0), [author pdf](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/farleyds/Far1.pdf)

proved that its universal cover is a  $CAT(0)$ cube complex. So indeed the Squier complex is a classifying space for $F$. The proof of all these from the category theory point of view can be found in Guba, V. S.; Sapir, M. V.
"Diagram groups and directed 2-complexes: homotopy and homology. "
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 205 (2006), no. 1, 1–47.